# including wordpress header in whmcs client area

Tags: php, css, wordpress, whmcs

For a project I'm working on I am trying to accomplish to match the whmcs client area to my wordpress site.
So far I've made a lot of progress but I'm stuck right now. I want to include the header of my wordpress site in whmcs. 
I tried to implement the static code of my header in the header.tpl file of whmcs. It kind of works but the css conflicts with the main theme of whmcs.

The second thing I tried was to include it with php

```
<?php include(path/to/header.php'); ?>
```

Since the header.php is located in the main www directory and whmc is on a subdomain, I was advised to try this:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php');
```

Neither of those two methods worked.

The next thing I did was a new approach. I tried implementing the whmcs layout in wordpress with a plugin called advanced Iframe. It does work but it doesn't always behave as it should and I think it is an better idea to keep whmcs completely on its own subdomain (client.domain.com)

I am no coding genius, so I'm stuck at this point. Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my mistake.
Since whmcs themes are .tpl, php can't be included directly and is not recommended. What I did was create a new folder in the theme directory with all the assets and a header.tpl file.
Then I included the header.tpl like this.

```
{include file="$template/header/header.tpl"}
```

The only downside is that I have to edit the menu manually when changes are made to the WordPress site

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file you're wanting to include the header in is in the same directory as `header.php`, then you can use

```
<?php include(__DIR__.'/header.php'); ?>
```